# empathy with webcam

Tags: webcam, empathy

When empathy will have camera support? and I have problem to change files with it too.
after 11.04 the next topic of canonical have to be to improve the empathy. the program is waek yet.

Comment: Would you please edit the title and text to specify that this is a question about MSN camera support in Empathy?  Also: what do you mean by "I have problem to change files with it too"?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using without problem the webcam in Empathy under Gtalk protocol (Gmail chat), and the videocall works well. It doesn't work with Yahoo or MSN yet...
Bye!

Comment: I would like to use the navite messenger. but pidgin it's a good choice. I hope in a few time we have support to webcam in msn messenger.

Answer (score 1):

It should have webcam support. I never tried it, but there is a webcam-symbol next to some people with the option to do video/audio calls. At least in ICQ.

Comment: have to gtalk too. I mean... the empathy need suport to msn messenger

Comment: Ok so your question is what is the status of MSN support in Empathy? Please edit your question and provide the detail.